# How to choose php version in .htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess, php5

I would like to install my PHP web application on a service that has two PHP versions, 4 and 5. I need PHP5, and I don't have access to `httpd.conf` due to server restrictions. How can I tell the Apache web server to choose PHP5 for this folder?

The server is Linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105632/change-php-version-on-server-using-either-htaccess-or-php-ini

Comment: http://docs.1h.com/How_to_switch_PHP_versions

Comment: how can I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between your installed PHP versions in several ways. If you are restricted to use `.htacess`, you may add a handler in your `.htacess` file. For example if you want to use PHP 4, you can add the following code to your `.htacess` file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php .php4 .php3
```

For PHP 5.0 you can use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

For PHP 5.1 you can use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Similarly for PHP 5.2 and 5.3. If you want PHP 5.2 with Suhosin patch use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52s .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

---

The answer can be found in the following links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105632/change-php-version-on-server-using-either-htaccess-or-php-ini

http://docs.1h.com/How_to_switch_PHP_versions

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)

Answer (score 0):

**You can check this link:-**

Try now:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server

http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_have_different_php__mysql_versions/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)